# Where did my Theme Editor go?

Tags: themes, child-theme, editor

I have 2 blogs, both are versions 3.x

One of them, "Blog 1" is a multi-user blog.  I can't edit the themes under Appearance->Editor , because it doesn't appear.

"Blog 2" is a single instance blog, and I can see the Appearance->Editor

What's the difference ?  How do I get the editor to appear ?  Could it be file permissions ?  If so, which directory(ies) do I need to check ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If the blog 1 is MU, then the editor is not available there by default.

Comment: Yes, it was MU.  How do I add it ?

Comment: You can't, without altering core.

Comment: Any other way to allow my users to modify themes, without creating a linux/ftp account ?

Comment: The dashboard editor is a massive security risk. Also keep in mind if a user edits a theme, they edit the theme for everybody. There is only 1 copy of the theme. Also keep in mind that they can horribly break their theme using the editor, sometimes in an unrecoverable way requiring a developer to use server file access to fix the issue

Comment: If you want to allow users to change how their theme looks, use the theme customiser to give them options, or provide a setting with a CSS text area so that they can override styling like wordpress.com does.

Answer (score 1):

The theme editor is not available on multisite installations. Changing this would require modifications to WordPress Core, that would need to be remade everytime you updated WordPress. I ***STRONGLY*** advise against this.

Also keep in mind that if one user edits a theme, everyone else using that theme gets the changes. There is only one copy. The editor also allows users to edit other themes, so users can modify other peoples sites on the network this way. It's also a **massive** security risk, a maintenance nightmare, and deprives you of future development work.

Instead I suggest you:

- Add theme options and settings for controlling the themes look
- Theme customiser options so that they have a nice UI to change things around, colours, text options, etc
- If they must add CSS, a setting with a text area like wordpress.com so that they can add CSS for the frontend. This way you can use some common javascript libraries to make editing the CSS much nicer than the editor you're trying to re-enable.

I'd also note that with the editor you desire, users can horribly break their websites. A single typo or error saved to `functions.php` can cripple all websites in your install using that theme. The same thing can happen to the entire network if it happens in a plugin, bringing down the entire multisite installation.

Answer (score 0):

In a WP MultiSite environment, your account needs to be a super-admin to be able to use the Theme Editor. Then navigate to **My Sites > Network Admin > Themes**. Then on the left side menu, you should see **Theme File Editor** under the themes menu (left side).